# Falta tradução no perfil de usuário que ainda não ganhou reputação

Tags: bug, tradução, localização

No perfil de qualquer usuário que ainda não ganhou nenhuma reputação é mostrada a seguinte frase:

> This user has no recent reputation changes

Veja a imagem:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]